# Is there a known error of Saxon-JS handling CDATA containing elements

Tags: xml, saxon, xslt-3.0, saxon-js

I'd like to know if there is a known error in the way Saxon-JS handles CDATA containing elements.

I have a working XSLT 3.0 and XML process that includes taking text from a CDATA containing element and applying HTML markup in the transformation. I'll try asking the question without posting the script.

I'm using Saxon-HE 9.8.0.3 and trying the lasted Saxon-JS.
Everything converted from the `.xsl` files to the `.sef` files works except the expected format of the text taken from the CDATA containing element.

I have an element `<docText>` that only contains `<![CDATA[ ... ]]>` enclosed multiline text.

I call the template with something like: 
`<xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::document/docText"/>`

I match with `<xsl:template match="docText/text()">`

The final manipulation of the text in `<docText>` contained in a variable is output with the following:
`<xsl:value-of select="$step9-2" disable-output-escaping="yes" />`

Again, the output is correct with working HTML markup when I use the original transformation with Saxon-HE, XML and XSLT 3.0 from command line in Java. The transform script is almost identical for use with Saxon-JS and all the logic works except the formatting of the text originally in the CDATA sections. The text is output but as unformatted.

Is there any reason the error might be due to the way Saxon-JS does or doesn't handle CDATA sections the way Saxon-HE does?

Michael

Comment: I wonder whether it is the CDATA section as you think or not simply the use of `disable-output-escaping`. How do you use XSLT 3 with Saxon-JS, is there any API use where you serialize a result so that `disable-output-escaping` could have any effect?

Comment: My XSLT is mostly 2.0 but I declared version="3.0" in the stylesheet. Maybe I should have mentioned I convert my .xsl file that has been modified to work with Saxon-JS to the .sef file with OxygenXML 19.1 . Without posting all the code, perhaps only the Saxon developers might be able to answer. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation/index.html#!conformance/xslt30 saying

> Saxon-JS does not implement the following optional features of the
>   specification: schema-awareness, serialization, streaming,
>   higher-order functions, and disable-output-escaping

Comment: I had not noticed the excluded features posted on the Saxon-JS site. But, I'm not sure that is the only issue. I don't see evidence that the call I listed above from `docText` was even matched to the template `docText/text()`. I tested by removing the matching template from my working solution and get the similar concatenation of text. Anyway, the exclusion you pointed out above at least lets me know I need to look for a different solution. Thanks for the time.

Comment: Built-in template rules would process the child nodes of any `docText` element not handled by your own templates and then built-in templates for text nodes would output the text node. So given the information you have posted so far and the restrictions of Saxon-JS the result seems as expected. What kind of context do you have in the CDATA section, can't you parse that with `parse-xml-fragment` into nodes and output them with `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:sequence`?

Comment: I've previously posted my context and you have made several helpful detailed responses. My CDATA has plain text with limited markup indicated by line endings, bracketed formatting marks/words and occasional HTML markup. With solutions you've suggested before, I can usually get about 80% of the way but always end up with some step I don't seem to be able to get past. My transformations create HTML documents and ePubs based on the content. Sometime I might go at it again. I did try `<xsl:value-of select="parse-xml-fragment($step9-2)/*" />` in place of the line I first posted. Thanks though.

Comment: Well, `xsl:value-of` will never create any element nodes, even if you manage to parse markup into element nodes, so you will have to use `xsl:copy-of` or `xsl:sequence` if you want to output element nodes. If the markup is not XML so that `parse-xml` or `parse-xml-fragment` does not work, then, as Michael pointed out, within Saxon-JS you can call into Javascript where `DOMParser` for complete documents or `Range.createContextualFragment` allow you to parse strings of HTML markup.

Comment: I have experimented with calling Javascript from Saxon-JS to use `createContextualFragment`, an example is at https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/2018/test201802190101.html, the source code of the files is online at https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/2018/test201802190101.html and https://github.com/martin-honnen/martin-honnen.github.io/blob/master/xslt/2018/test201802190101.xsl. HTH

Comment: I tried changing `xsl:value-of select` to `xsl:sequence select="parse-xml-fragment($var)"` this recovered the HTML formatted content with one problem I'm trying to decipher. Whenever it encounters html like this example `<span epub:type="pagebreak" id="page130" title="130">[page 130] 129</span>` the remainder of the record is cut off. The next record is displayed correctly until a similar html fragment is reached then same thing. I was going to stop trying this pathway yesterday but I appreciate your persistence and time. I'll study your other suggestions. Thanks for the code samples. MB

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a known issue: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/3385

Without seeing more of your code, I'm not sure whether that issue is relevant. The bug says that CDATA sections are converted to text nodes if there is any whitespace stripping in effect, but not otherwise, so a useful experiment would be to see what happens if you add to your stylesheet

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="a-dummy-element-name"/>
```

This will trigger whitespace stripping which also has the effect of turning CDATA nodes into ordinary text nodes.

However, this isn't going to solve the problem that your code is reliant on disable-output-escaping. If your CDATA/text node contains HTML markup that needs to be copied into the HTML page, the only way to do this under Saxon-JS is to parse the HTML into a tree of nodes, and add the nodes to the HTML DOM. If the HTML is well-formed XML you can do this using the parse-xml() function; if not, you may have to call out to Javascript.

Comment: I will check the whitespace stripping situation. Regardless I probably wont get the output I need without disable-output-escaping without a total rewrite of the working code I have now. My main goal was to use a form to enter a parameter that I was previously entering in the command line using with Saxon-HE. That's why I wanted to experiment with Saxon-JS. It worked except I wasn't getting the formatting from content that started in CDATA sections for the reason you and Martin point out. Thank you for responding.